# How to define vector getting invalid use of template- name std::vector without an argument list

Tags: c++, vector, header

I tried to implement the vector defined in the header but I don't know how.

**.hpp file:**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_HPP
#define CUSTOMER_HPP
#include<vector>
#include "Product.hpp"

{
    private:
        std::vector cart;        
        std::string name;        
        std::string accountID;        
        bool premiumMember;

    public:    
        Customer(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm);        
        std::string getAccountID();
        std::vector getCart();
        void addProductToCart(std::string);
        bool isPremiumMember();
        void emptyCart();
};

#endif
```

This is the implementation file I am writing for the header, there are some errors.  I don't know how to write the implementation for the vector.

**.cpp implementation:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.hpp"

using namespace std;

string accountID;
bool premiumMember;

Customer::Customer(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm)
{
    name=n;
    accountID=a;    
    premiumMember=pm;       
}

std::string Customer:: getAccountID()
{
    return accountID;
}

void Customer:: addProductToCart(accountID,std::vector<string>cart)
{
    vector<string>::Type intVector; cart;
    cart.pushback(accountID);
}

bool Customer:: isPremiumMember()
{
    return premiumMember;
}

void Customer:: emptyCart()
{
    cart.clear();
}
```

Comment: vector<string>::Type intVector; cart; whats this use vector<string> intVector, cart;

Comment: sry i was trying different ways that shouldnt be there. Ignore that i want to know how to write implementation for that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector you have defined in your Customer class: `std::vector cart;` is not a correctly defined type. You need to specify what *type* a vector is supposed to contain.

`std::vector<std::string> cart;`

Your method `getCart` is also using an incomplete type and should be `std::vector<std::string> getCart()`.

Then, your declaration of this method:

`void addProductToCart(std::string);`

Does not match the definition:

`void Customer:: addProductToCart(accountID,std::vector<string>cart)`

I suspect you want that method to look like this:

```
void Customer:: addProductToCart(std::string item)
{
     cart.pushback(item);
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the help :) it looks like it worked. Now  its not showing any error. now i have another method std::vector getCart(); how to return the vector from that function